# How to combine multiple columns with missing data into one?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, merge

I have a (very messy) dataset that is the product of the merging of a few datasets. It currently looks like this:

```
   Study_ID Status Death_status death
1       100      1           NA    NA
2       200      1           NA    NA
3       300      0           NA    NA
4       400     NA            0    NA
5       500     NA            1    NA
6       600     NA            0    NA
7       700     NA           NA     0
8       800     NA           NA     1
9       900     NA           NA     1
10     1000     NA           NA     0
```

I would like to create a new column that combines all 3 of the columns for each patient.

My desired output would look something like this:

```
   Study_ID New_Death_Status Status Death_status death
1       100                1      1           NA    NA
2       200                1      1           NA    NA
3       300                0      0           NA    NA
4       400                0     NA            0    NA
5       500                1     NA            1    NA
6       600                0     NA            0    NA
7       700                0     NA           NA     0
8       800                1     NA           NA     1
9       900                1     NA           NA     1
10     1000                0     NA           NA     0
```

Where New_Death_Status has a full set of data for every patient.

How can I go about doing this?

Reproducible data:

```
data<-data.frame(Study_ID=c("100","200","300","400","500","600","700","800","900","1000"),Status=c("1","1","0","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA"),Death_status=c("NA","NA","NA","0","1","0","NA","NA","NA","NA"),death=c("NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","NA","0","1","1","0"))
> data
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming we *know* that know patient will have more than one column (meaning we can safely ignore everything after the first column with non-`NA` data), then we can `coalesce` it.

However ... your data has literal `"NA"` strings instead of the reserveds symbol `NA`. I think that may be a mistake in your processing somewhere, so I'll "fix" them to be `NA` (and still strings):

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  mutate(
    # this step just replaces the literal "NA" with the symbol NA
    across(c(Status, Death_status, death), ~ if_else(. == "NA", .[NA], .)),
    New_Death_Status = coalesce(Status, Death_status, death)
  )
#    Study_ID Status Death_status death New_Death_Status
# 1       100      1         <NA>  <NA>                1
# 2       200      1         <NA>  <NA>                1
# 3       300      0         <NA>  <NA>                0
# 4       400   <NA>            0  <NA>                0
# 5       500   <NA>            1  <NA>                1
# 6       600   <NA>            0  <NA>                0
# 7       700   <NA>         <NA>     0                0
# 8       800   <NA>         <NA>     1                1
# 9       900   <NA>         <NA>     1                1
# 10     1000   <NA>         <NA>     0                0
```

`coalesce` returns the first non-`NA` found among its vector arguments, so it will silently discard any subsequent non-`NA` value present. Also, it will complain if all of the classes are not the same; they are all strings here, but if your processing is changing classes